# Creating formflows in SDK-4.0

Tags: botframework, formflow

I'm trying to replicate the formflow dialog as present in SDk-3.0 in SDK-4.0 bot framework using c# but unable to get any kind of documentation or sample code.
Is it possible to create them?
If yes: if anyone has tried implementing the same please share the document or any sample code.

Thanks,
Karthi

Answer (score 0):

While the official Bot Framework SDK didn't create a v4 version of FormFlow, the BotBuilder-Community has successfully created a one, found [here](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/master/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow). The muget packages can be downloaded from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow/) or simply installed via the nuget package manager on Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: i have created a sdk4 from azure portal and trying to use the custom build luis but i am not exactly getting it.

Comment: I have created a sdk4 from azure portal and trying to use the custom build luis app but I am not exactly getting it.The code which is working for greetings which is already present in code as well as working for prebuild luis app(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-csharp-tutorial-bf-v4).

Comment: I would like to know how the code is working with prebuild app?                                                                                                                How to add custom build luis app in code(C#). Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, I have built a bot by using this sample and it works well on local, but when i publish on azure it publishes as a web app. Next I created a bot channel registration and provided web app endpoint to bot channel registration. But it is still not working. Checking logs of bot gives following error - "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code NotFound"